# Apply limits on tweets

Tags: python, tweepy, data-retrieval

I am trying to fetch twitters data in python using tweepy, I want to set the number of tweets returned.
Here is my block of code

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(track=['hello', 'javascript', 'python'])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to set the number of tweets returned" ? do you want to track the number of tweets received ?

Comment: sir, how many tweets we can get. Is it based on our consumer key?

Comment: basically i am searching the tweets on the basis of keywords. So is there any limit that we cannot exceed it..??? What is that limit?

Comment: Now my code looks like                                                                                            , auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
search_hashtag = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='imran khan',include_entities=True).items(1)

  for tweet in search_hashtag:
    print(json.dumps(tweet._json, indent=1))

Comment: what if i dont set the limit ? thn how many tweets it returns>

Comment: The STREAM api is never ended, so you can get forever tweets, there is no limit. With the public search API, you can get at most 100 tweets per request not older than 7 days (and 1 request each 5 seconds). Read : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html and https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter.html

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy provides the convenient Cursor interface to iterate through different types of objects. Twitter allows a maximum of 3200 tweets for extraction.

Set the return tweets in par page to 50:

```
tweets = api.search(q="place:%s" % place_id, rpp=50)
```